# Why my application shows in battery after exit android application?

Tags: android, exit, battery

**Screens**

---

[image: Battery Drains]

**Problems**

---

**1) It drains lots of battery.**

**2) After Exit application it display in battery status.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This number is not a current battery use but a percentage of battery used since last charge.

To fix this, you need to optimize your program and performance profile it. When it's running, it is using a lot of battery.

Comment: @Darshak: "Can you give me any proof of that statement?" -- you are welcome to rummage through the Android source code for "proof". Or, you could notice that the entire screen is driven around the concept of time (hint: it even *shows the amount of time* on the screen). You might also stop and consider what the alternative would be if it were *not* based on time: the only entry that would ever appear would be the Settings app on single-core devices, as the Settings app is the only thing that is running at that instant. This would be useless.